# How to merge several GML files into one

Tags: ogr, gml

I have a folder of GML files that I want to be able to merge to create one GML file that I can then view.
I have tried this using [the code described](http://darrencope.com/2010/05/07/merge-a-directory-of-shapefiles-using-ogr/) but searching for GML in this website without result.

The code I used was:

```
mkdir merged 
for %f in (*.gml) do (
if not exist merged\merged.gml (
ogr2ogr -f "GML" merged\merged.gml %f) 
else (
ogr2ogr -f "GML" -update -append merged\merged.gml %f -nln Merged )
)
```

For clarity the files are for the OS mastermap topography data.

Forgot to say I get the following error message several times when I run the code.

> C:\OSMM_GMLS>(if not exist merged\merged.gml (ogr2ogr -f "GML"
>   merged\merged.gml  M00001177-SX6590-5c296.gml )  else (ogr2ogr -f
>   "GML" -update -append merged\mer ged.gml M00001177-SX6590-5c296.gml
>   -nln Merged  ) ) FAILURE: Unable to open existing output datasource `merged\merged.gml'.

Comment: Could you say what happens? OGR should tell you if it's unhappy.

Comment: Add the error message now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Matt T: does the merged directory get created? Is there a file in it?

Comment: @DarrenCope Matt's responded, but it's in one of the questions below as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The suggested solution ([on my website](http://darrencope.com/2010/05/07/merge-a-directory-of-shapefiles-using-ogr/)) works great for shapefiles. However, .gml is a bit different, and according to [this page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html), GML does not support the 'update' function. See the first line on that page:

> OGR has limited support for GML reading and writing. **Update of existing files is not supported.**

Shaunak's solution may be best; convert to another format. You could always convert that back to GML when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if your error is in part beacause `-nln Merged` may not be a valid layer in the GML file.

Run `ogrinfo -ro -so input.gml` to see what the layer name(s) are.

Example:

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads>ogrinfo -ro -so 001l11_5_0.gml
INFO: Open of `001l11_5_0.gml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
1: TR_1750009_1 (Multi Line String)
2: LI_1210009_2 (Multi Polygon)
```

So in the case of merging several of the above gmls, I would try to use an existing layername, either option 1 ("TR_1750009_1") or 2 ("LI_1210009_2").

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not specified the error, I am presenting a alternate approach which may work for you. The blog post you have mentioned in question works on shapefiles. Why not try converting gml to shapefiles, then merge and then write back the gml? here is the tool:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: Darren: The folder does get created and there is a gml file created. When I view this in QGIS though it only displays as one the original singular gmls not as a merged version of the original six in the directory.