# How to merge two *.gml files with different geometry types into one gml file

Tags: gdal, merge, ogr2ogr, gml

I have two gml files one contains linear data and the other one contains polygon data. I want to have the correct ogr command to merge the two gml files into one file.

I found this answer from 2012 that says ogr does not provide full support for gml data:

[How to merge several GML files into one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30348/how-to-merge-several-gml-files-into-one)

I am wondering if it is possible in 2023 with ogr2ogr.

I already asked ChatGPT and it gave me few commands that throw error:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GML" merged.gml 1.gml -update -append 2.gml
```

that gave me this error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to open existing output datasource `merged.gml'.
```

I also used this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GML" "C:\path\to\directory\merged.gml" 1.gml
ogr2ogr -f "GML" -update -append "C:\path\to\directory\merged.gml" 2.gml -nln merged_layer
```

that gave me this error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to open existing output datasource `merged.gml'.
```

I also checked the access rights and it was ok I also ran the CMD as Admin.

Does anyone know the ogr command to merge 2 gml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking a drunk friend (or chatGPT) why not look at the [actual documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html#vector-gml)

> OGR has limited support for GML reading and writing. Update of existing files is not supported.

So it won't work.

Comment: :D thanks for the funny comment and answer

Comment: then, if ogr2ogr cannot merge GML files, what is the best way to merge two gml files? In QGIS I was not able to do it

Comment: you could merge them into say a geopackage and then export that as GML

Comment: Yes, finally I converted both of them to GeoPackage and them merged the GeoPckages using Ogr2ogr tool and then I converted the gpkg file to a gml with two layers using ogr2ogr. Finally, I imported them into PostGIS using ogr2ogr.

Comment: @milad - you could make that an answer and then accept it