# QGIS 3.0 Vertex Tool Grayed Out

Tags: vertices

I have a simple line added as a layer from a KML file.  I can select the features and show numerous nodes.  It is in edit mode.  Normally I would expect to be able to delete a node, split a line, etc. but none of the advanced digitizing works.  The vertex tool is grayed out.  I get the error "CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool".  I have scoured Google and am at a loss.

Comment: related: OGR driver https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22673/why-cant-i-edit-kml-gml-layers/22678#22678

Answer (score 4):

To enable vertex editing your layer needs to have a column set as Primary Key. This is not possible in some data formats.

Answer (score 1):

Not probably the correct way to do things but I selected Vector/Geometry Tools/Simplify/Run in Background.  This created a new layer titled "added geom info" which I was then able to edit with the Vertex tools.  Hopefully someone can answer why I needed to go to that additional step as it is not intuitive.  The KML file was created from Google My Maps highlighting a route so it must have to do something with the line being a coordinate or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem- Imported a .kmz polygon and it could not be edited.  Solution is to go to vector-Geoprocessing-dissolve.  As default, a new layer named 'Dissolved' is created. This can be edited.
Rename this to your original file and delete the imported file.

Answer (score 0):

I imported a kmz file from Google Earth and had the same problem. I was able to solve it by exporting the map on QGIS and saving as ESRI shapefile. With this you can successfully use the vertex tool.