# "Vertex Tool" only for some PostGIS Layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I want to edit PostGIS layers within QGIS and before that, I changed a layer using `ST_Difference`. Now, I can select QGIS' Edit Feature after importing it from PostGIS but only for some layers it is possible (which I haven't changed) to change their vertices with the Vertex Tool.

I checked SRID, Geometry Type and so on but couldn't find a difference. Has anyone ever faced the same problem?

Comment: a common issue with derived layers is if they don't have a primary key defined

Answer (score 2):

I figured out fast, and for the others: As already stated by JGH and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333295/72983), a primary key has to be defined and since my table had no and even no natural primary, I had to summarize my geoms to get one.
Thanks!